# Compiler error: "does not name a type" in macro when compiling with g++

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to create a macro to delete the copy and move constructors of a class.
This code fails to compile on GCC 4.8.2 with ". What is wrong with it?
If I put everything on a single line the code compiles.

```
#define DISALLOW_COPY_AND_MOVE(ClassName)                   \
    ClassName(const ClassName&) KEYWORD_DELETE;             \  // Copy constructor
    ClassName& operator=(const ClassName&) KEYWORD_DELETE;  \  // Copy assignment operator
    ClassName(ClassName &&) KEYWORD_DELETE;                 \  // Move constructor
    ClassName& operator=(ClassName&&) KEYWORD_DELETE;          // Move assignment operator
```

The second line does not issue a compiler error but the last three lines do.

KEYWORD_DELETE is just:

```
#if defined CPP11
    #define KEYWORD_DELETE = delete
#else
    #define KEYWORD_DELETE
#endif // defined CPP11
```

This is the output:

```
In file included from ..\ObjectSlicing\src\main.cpp:5:0:
..\ObjectSlicing\src\__rm_utilities__/__rm_utilities__.h:26:5: error: stray '\' in program
     ClassName& operator=(const ClassName&) KEYWORD_DELETE;  \  // Copy assignment operator
     ^
..\ObjectSlicing\src\__rm_utilities__/__rm_utilities__.h:27:5: error: stray '\' in program
     ClassName(ClassName &&) KEYWORD_DELETE;                 \  // Move constructor
     ^
In file included from ..\ObjectSlicing\src\__include__/animals:5:0,
                 from ..\ObjectSlicing\src\main.cpp:6:
..\ObjectSlicing\src\__include__/../animals/cat.h:28:5: error: stray '\' in program
     DISALLOW_COPY_AND_MOVE(Cat)
     ^
In file included from ..\ObjectSlicing\src\__include__/animals:6:0,
                 from ..\ObjectSlicing\src\main.cpp:6:
..\ObjectSlicing\src\__include__/../animals/dog.h:28:5: error: stray '\' in program
     DISALLOW_COPY_AND_MOVE(Dog)
     ^
In file included from ..\ObjectSlicing\src\main.cpp:5:0:
..\ObjectSlicing\src\__rm_utilities__/__rm_utilities__.h:26:5: error: 'ClassName' does not name a type
     ClassName& operator=(const ClassName&) KEYWORD_DELETE;  \  // Copy assignment operator
     ^
..\ObjectSlicing\src\__rm_utilities__/__rm_utilities__.h:27:14: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
     ClassName(ClassName &&) KEYWORD_DELETE;                 \  // Move constructor
              ^
..\ObjectSlicing\src\__rm_utilities__/__rm_utilities__.h:28:5: error: 'ClassName' does not name a type
     ClassName& operator=(ClassName&&) KEYWORD_DELETE;          // Move assignment operator
     ^
```

Comment: `\\` in macro must be the last character before newline

Comment: that you can't put the comments in there?

Comment: The slash in the macro definition must be the last character on the line, or it doesn't work (you must either remove the comments or put them before the slash)

Comment: and does it make sense to have a macro for C++11 use then not use it for move semantics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't spot `error: stray '\' in program`?

The caret is in the wrong place; it should be pointing to the backslash:

```
..\ObjectSlicing\src\__rm_utilities__/__rm_utilities__.h:26:5: error: stray '\' in program
     ClassName& operator=(const ClassName&) KEYWORD_DELETE;  \  // Copy assignment operator
                                                             ^ -- here
```

You can't put a `//` comment after a backslash line continuator; if you want to embed comments in a macro you need to use `/* */` comments and put them *before* the backslash.

Answer (score 1):

one other cause may be is that:
if you are working with classes and friend function and if u had called that class in your friend function which you would not have declared before calling that function-----like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//class Second;
class first{

public:
    int val1;
    void setVal(int tval){
        val1=tval;
    }
    void display(){
        cout<<"in first value 1 is:"<<val1<<endl;
    }

    friend Second sum(first fobj,Second sobj);      
   };
  class Second{
  public:
  int val2;
    void setVal(int tval){
        val2=tval;
    }
    void display(){
        cout<<"in second value 2 is:"<<val2<<endl;
    }
    friend Second sum(first fobj,Second sobj);      
 };
Second sum(first fobj,Second sobj){
Second rel;
rel.val2=fobj.val1+sobj.val2;
return rel;
} 

int main(){
first f1;
Second s1;
f1.setVal(50);
s1.setVal(2);
f1.display();
s1.display();

Second rel=sum(f1,s1);
rel.display();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: g++ compiler will error when you run the code so you b=need to uncomment the 3rd line run again